# AsyncTask is not responding to every click?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have some problem with Android AsyncTask.In the Fragment i use async task for streaming a audio from url. At first play button it executes without any problem but when i click to go to next song the UI skip the song when i click again in next button then its working fine. It means i have to click two times to execute next button functionality.Here is my async task class:

```
 private class LodingToFetchMp3Url extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();


        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...!");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Constants.musicArrayListConstants.get(position).getMp3FileUrl());
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); // you must call this method after setup the datasource in setDataSource method. After calling prepare() the instance of MediaPlayer starts load data from URL to internal buffer.

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); // gets the song length in milliseconds from URL

        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {



            mediaPlayer.start();
            imgPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.btn_pause_black);
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            imgPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.btn_play);
        }

        primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();  method:

```
  private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
    seekBarProgress.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds) * 100)); // This math construction give a percentage of "was playing"/"song length"


    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification, 100);
    }
}
```

Next Button onClick :

```
else if (v.getId() == R.id.imgNext) {

        if(Constants.dropsModelArrayListConstants.size() > position) {
            position = position + 1;

            mediaPlayer.pause();
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            lodingToFetchMp3Url.cancel(true);

            lodingToFetchMp3Url = new LodingToFetchMp3Url();
            lodingToFetchMp3Url.execute();
        }

    }
```

Comment: when you click the next button whether the pause icon changes to play icon?

Comment: yes pause icon changes to play icon but mp3 url file does not executes. so i have to click again on next button to execute. then its work fine

Comment: no thats not a problem its just for start and pause media player i checked it

Comment: Can you please pause the audio and click next and check what happens?

Comment: Can you please pause the audio and click next and check what happens? --> in this case works fine.

Comment: That's what check the condition in onPostExecute because while one audio is playing you are trying to shift to next audio by a button click where the async task is initialised. at that time your media player state in the async thread is still playing which lead to pause the player and change the icon to play. Kindly debug and check the scenario.

Comment: can you please explain with e.g.

Comment: Can you add your code in Git where I can see and edit?

Comment: please give solution here only if u can. edit changes only